# Using constants in a PDO connection string and calling a function with a PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo, constants

I'm having problems with using constants in a PDO connection and when calling a function containing a PDO connection.

I'm using the function to connect the the DB only when needed. On pages where no DB work is needed, there's no need to connect.

I've tried a lot, but can't figure where I'm going wrong.

```
<?php
/** The name of the database */
define('DB_NAME', 'dev-db');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dxdb');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

function connect(){
try
    {**//Here's where the first problem is**
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=DB_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME',DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

connect();// Here's where it fails again

$sql = 'insert into names (names) values (:what)';
$what = "testValue";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':what', $what, PDO::PARAM_STR, 5);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You have to concatenate the string like this `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME .',DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);`

Comment: Oh! The old stuff did not need concatenation ``$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);`` So I thought it'd be the same here.

Comment: Well, how would PHP tell that `echo 'DB_HOST';` is a string or a constant ? It's a string :-)

Comment: Ok. That solved problem one. Any idea how to do the next problem? The function..

Comment: @YourCommonSense ``Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\web\apache\htdocs\index.php on line 29 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\web\apache\htdocs\index.php on line 29``

Comment: See how it is important to read error messages. Remember to provide an error message every time you asks a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this question has nothing to do with PDO, but rather with PHP *strings*.

So, the question is, "How to use a constant in a string?".

And the answer is fairly simple - concatenate them with strings.

Also, the way you are connecting is wrong. Refer to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for the proper way

Your second issue has nothing to do with PDO again, being just [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. Just make your function return `$conn` variable, and then call it

```
$conn = connect();
```

Also, there is no point in defining separate constants for host and database in case of using PDO - DSN is a distinct entity, similar to HOST in other drivers.

So, the code could be (though I am not sure if dev-db being valid database name):

```
define('DB_DSN', 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev-db;charset=utf8');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dxdb');

function connect() 
{
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    return new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, $opt);
}
$conn = connect();
```

Answer (score 3):

better way is direct use connect statement, there is no need of function in your case.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME , DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Actually, I want to use the function so I can connect only when needed. I put it all together here for this question. Else, the constants are in one file, the connection in another. The connection will run even if it doesn't have to.